# Java gRPC server-side streaming payload size limit

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I'm confused about the relationship between the protobuf size limit and the payload size of each `.onNext` call. AFAIK, in Java, we have a `int32` size limit (~2gb) for each protobuf object, while the default `.onNext` payload size limit is 4mb but can be configured to unlimited. Does it mean the maximum payload size of each `.onNext` call is 2gb?

Comment: How can you configure the inbound message size to be unlimited? Looking at the docs for `io.grpc.ServerBuilder.maxInboundMessageSize()` the param is an int32 which means you can only set it to MAXINT i.e. 2GB and that's what you are limited to

Comment: yes, you are right. We are using NettyServer to set the inbound limit like this: `NettyServerBuilder.maxInboundMessageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and what is your issue?

Comment: My confusion is that, where is the 2gb payload size limit in gRPC coming from? Is it that, say we use protobuf, you cannot create a protobuf object with size large than 2gb or gRPC simply cannot transmit data large than 2GB?